# Combine 2 flow but keep it as flow

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, coroutine

```
 val animeHistory: Flow<PagingData<Anime>> = useCases
        .getAnimeHistory()
        .cachedIn(viewModelScope)

 val animeWatchList: Flow<PagingData<Anime>> = useCases
        .getAnimeWatchList()
        .cachedIn(viewModelScope)
```

So, i have 2 flows like this, and wanted to expose this to UI with a single flow by using data class.

```
data class CollectionState(
    val history: Flow<PagingData<Anime>> = flowOf(),
    val watchList: Flow<PagingData<Anime>> = flowOf(),
)
```

But the problem here is, i cannot combine 2 flows and persist it as flow at the same time. If i use `combine` it will transform both flow into PagingData and i cannot use this at UI with compose. Is there a way to achieve this? Or alternative for this?

Comment: There are two flows in your data class, not a single one. And as far as I see, the question concerns the combining of Pages rather than Flows, I would create the combined flow before the Pager.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I understand what you actually want to achieve, but looking at the code it seems reasonable that you want to merge the two flows into one while also transforming their content into a `CollectionState` that will then be wrapped into a single flow. You would need to change the data class to this, first:

```kotlin
data class CollectionState(
    val history: PagingData<Anime>,
    val watchList: PagingData<Anime>,
)
```

After all, exposing a flow of flows to compose wouldn't make any sense.

Then to create the final ui state that you'll want to expose to compose will be as simple as this:

```kotlin
val uiState: Flow<CollectionState> = combine(animeHistory, animeWatchList) { history, watchList ->
    CollectionState(
        history = history,
        watchList = watchList,
    )
}
```

You should probably make this to a `StateFlow` by calling `stateIn` on it.

You now have *one* flow that contains the content of both the other flows as a `CollectionState` which gets updated whenever any of them produces a new value.